# How to I feed features to keras model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, feature-selection

I am trying to get some hands-on experience with ML and learning how to train a model able to predict gender from name.

I vectorize the names (have played with three different ways to do this) and pass them as input to the model but as much as I played with it, I can only get the model be so accurate (about 70% max).

At this point, with 32K names in my corpus, I have pretty much depleted my sources of additional names (and after all, if I keep racing for additional names, my dictionary would at some point get large enough to not need the AI anyways).

So I thought that I could "help" my network by giving it hints about the names to help it elevate its accuracy level.

If I understand features correctly, I could use them to help model establish better accuracy by giving it additional characteristics that help predict class with higher accuracy.

For instance these:

```
<QuerySet [{'gender': 'Female', 'ends_with_a': 8089}, {'gender': 'Male', 'ends_with_a': 677}]>,
<QuerySet [{'gender': 'Female', 'ends_with_na': 1710}, {'gender': 'Male', 'ends_with_na': 93}]>
```

Names ending with `a` are more likely to belong to females. And so on. I could not find tools that automatically synthesis features from words, so I guess I would have to figure and extract them myself as this point.

What I don't understand is **how to pass these features to the model** without having the model ask for these features when I ask it to predict the class for me.

After I prepared my data, it's a pandas frame:

```
        gender  gender_count    name    vectorized   indexised  nlp_vectorized
20908   1       5               jasmely [0, ..]      [9, ...]   [0.44732133, 0.5620067 ...]
```

I use of the vectorized inputs into the model to train it:

```py
X = names_frame["vectorized"].values
X = np.array([np.array(l) for l in X])
Y = names_frame["gender"].values
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=26, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=40, batch_size=500, validation_split=.2, callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras()], verbose=False)
```

I can add the features to my `dataframe` with data, but how do I feed it to the model?

Comment: I am a bit confused have you seen `model.predict()` and not understood it and want an example code?, or you hadn't heard of `model.predict()`?

Comment: I did play with predict after training the model. I give it a single sample and it will predict the class output for it. What I am trying to get is how to pass additional input to the model for its training.

Comment: So you want to train your model on more data?

Comment: Or are you looking how to save the progress that you have made after training your model, then when you open again, you can train with more data and Improve your model?

Comment: I understand how to save the model and use it to predict things (at least I think I do lol). I am trying to understand how instead of _just_ giving the model the names vectors and gender (0/1), give the model additional input: such as: `name ends with an a` or such to help it train better.

Comment: Whenever you build a model, you have to define the number of input features in advance, suppose you want to add a feature after the fact, you can try adding it to the last layer and building a neural net on top. i.e. Another model which contains outputs of the previous model and the new input. However that is not a recommended strategy

Comment: I would always encourage you to identify all the important features at the beginning of model training.

Comment: in the code above I basically pass just one pandas column for X - if I generated another two columns for features, how do I add this to the training? I thought that if I just extend my X, the model will be asking for this same input for `predict()` too?

Comment: If you want to add more columns to your training/Testing Data you can use `pd.concat()` and yes the dimensions of data for training, testing and predicting should be same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188533/discussion-between-abolotnov-and-anand-v-singh).